# I want to send information through notification

Tags: android, mobile, push-notification

I am making an app for my university, now in which I want to send messages/information about events. How I can send info to them. I tried firebase but, it is working till push notification only. I want if someone clicks on the notification it should open a new activity with whole message/info any code reference will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getnotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationmgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, your_acitivity.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), new Intent[]{intent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.shadow_fiend)
            .setContentTitle(notif_title)//Title of the notification
            .setContentText(notif_detail)//Description of the notification
            .setContentIntent(pintent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    notificationmgr.notify(0, notif);

}
```

When the above function is called a notification is generated and by clicking the notification the user is redirected to a specific activity. In the intent replace the your_acitivity.class to whatever activity you want to be redirected when notification is clicked.

Feel free to comment if I misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: Bilal, my message will be around 200 words.Is it possible with firebase?

Answer (score 0):

use the payload to put information into your notification. this could be an event id. The text of your notification is is also set by your server.

Thanks to the payload, your app client knows what event ID was received with the notification (when notification was opened). Just ask your database about information from the received event id from the client and you have all you need.